# Essay "link" in chinese?

Tags: translation

In my school they teach a PEEL format for writing essays.

Point-论点

Evidendence-论据

Explanation-论证

Link-????

What is the "link" known as in Chinese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link

**连接**、**联系**

[英语作文怎么写好内容丰富 百度知道](http://zhidao.baidu.com/link?url=iBivQkPTgOKbr7amIiAXlQGcS0w2aP6yirio3C_7L-iIasVC2eLwgaZHKUv_LfMU-8cnE2kNb012_YNN6PjY3hmJrwniho8tW7XKxqSRKfm)

> 提问者采纳
>
> 英语作文有4点：PEEL【point、evidence、explain、link】就是要提出一个点、再找出几个例子、用几个段落解释这几个例子、每段落最后一句要可以**连接**到下一节的内容、这样就能写出一篇较好的英语作文了。【我们老师就是这样教的】

[[XLS] Sheet1](https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0mMTMpYPMAhVDKqYKHe5LA28QFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Facsbr.moe.edu.sg%2Fwbn%2Fslot%2Fu1258%2FSec%25204%25265%2520CL%2520Scope%2520and%2520Sequences%2520T1%2520T2%25202014%2520.xlsx&usg=AFQjCNGAxdg-EWl0rFTEBHVEuFsxTOG58w&bvm=bv.119028448,d.dGY)

> 论点、申论、举例、**联系**（PEEL）。

> PEEL
>
> Points/Topic Sentence
>
> Elaboration/Examples
>
> Link/Summary
>
> 段落主句
>
> 扩展／例子
>
> **联系**主旨／段落总结